# jquery slider and nav clashing. Help!

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, navigation, slider

I am building a site that uses two jquery plugins: A [Jquery Menu](http://apycom.com/menus/1-dim-gray.html) (that I modified a bit) and the [JFlow slider](http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/using-the-wonderful-jflow-plugin-screencast/). I have uploaded the page that Im having the problem [here](http://www.vitaminjdesign.com/nav/).

For some reason, the file menu.js (that is the engine behind the nav bar) causes the slider to stop working. When I remove the line of code:`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
```

` the slider works perfectly. Something in that file is causing the slider not to work! I can't seem to figure out whats causing this clash, so please let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found the solution [here](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4392). You need to change the easing mode from "swing" to linear on the jflow plugin controls. Then it works great!

Comment: I would STILL like to use the swing easing and not the linear. IF someone can figure out a real solution, not a workaround that would be great.